# Class name is invalid or already implemented in the selected source file

Tags: visual-c++, dll, visual-studio-2017, v4-printer-driver

I have a solution in VS2017 including 7 different C# or C++ projects. I add a new project to generate a dynamic link library (.dll) and then trying to create a new class in the newly created project using add option. But I get the following message:

"Class 'sampleProvider' is either invalid or already implemented in the selected source file."

Previously, I have defined a class with the same name in a project of the current solution, but then I have removed and deleted the project and all relevant references.

I checked the windows registry. There is no any entry, key or value in the windows registry with the same name. Also there is no any file in the windows file system with the same name.

But in my solution directory in a hidden folder named ".vs" in '...\.vs\MySolutionName\v14' there are two files named '.suo' and 'Browse.VC.db' which include few references to old class name. I know that '.suo' is a file includes 'Visual Studio Solution User Options' and 'Browse.VC.db' is IDE Database File. I am not pretty sure what happens if I delete these two files or all mentioned references from these two. Dose it possible to define my own class with my preferred name, afterwards?

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: Did you check if the file `sampleProvider.cs` already exists in destination folder? Check this through system file explorer and not through Visual Studio.

Comment: Two things: first it is a VC++ not a C# project. Second, even in c#, the .cs file (.cpp and .h files in VC++ projects) could be generated automatically when user tries to create a new class using "add, class" option in pop-up menu over the project in VS.

Comment: Yes, and if you delete a project from the solution, it is just **removed**, not deleted. I just try to make sure that the file does not exist in dest.